# Nhibernate and SQLite Exception "Cannot write to a Closed TextWriter"

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, sqlite

I'm trying to use NHibernate with SQLite for Unit Testing. But I'm keep getting error

> ADOException was unhandled by user code
>   While preparing INSERT INTO User (First_Name, Last_Name, UserName, Password, Email, Active, Default_Clinic_Identification_Number, Login_Icon, Created_Date, Created_By, Modified_Date, Modified_By) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11); select last_insert_rowid() an error occurred
>
> Inner Exception: {"Cannot write to a closed TextWriter."}

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Here is my code

```
public class InMemoryDatabaseTest : IDisposable
{
    private static Configuration Configuration;
    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
    protected ISession session;

    public InMemoryDatabaseTest()
    {
        if (Configuration == null)
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.Load("Astute.Framework.Data");

            Configuration = new Configuration()
                .SetProperty(Environment.ReleaseConnections, "on_close")
                .SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof(SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(SQLite20Driver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, "data source=:memory:")
                .SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof(ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .AddAssembly(a);

            SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();

        new SchemaExport(Configuration).Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, Console.Out);
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        session.Dispose();

    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Test : InMemoryDatabaseTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanSaveUser()
    {
        object id;

        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            id = session.Save(new User
            {
                FirstName = "Imran",
                LastName = "Ashraf",
                UserName = "imran",
                Password = "Test",
                Email = "Test@test.com",
                IsActive = true,
                DefaultClinicIdentifcationNumber = "",
                LoginIcon = "",
                CreatedBy = 1000000,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Today,
                ModifiedBy = 1000000,
                ModifiedDate = DateTime.Today
            });

            tx.Commit();
        }

        session.Clear();

    }
}
```

I'm getting error on this line  id = session.Save. I got this example from http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Comment: Maybe a sample project could give a hint. Because the Model and Mappings are not included.

Comment: I have the same issue when using this example with mstest. However it works with Nunit.

Answer (score 2):

The error message *"Inner Exception: {"Cannot write to a closed TextWriter."}"* is given when you are trying to write into the `Console.Out`.

I created a new `TextWriter` and used it:

```
TextWriter writer = null;
new SchemaExport(Configuration).Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, writer);
```

That fixed that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem. I use this as connection string:

```
Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;
```

You may try it to see if it solves the problem. The `New=True;` part looks promising.

Comment: No It didn't solve my problem. I'm using following versions

Version of NHibernate is 2.1.2.4000
Version of System.Data.SQLite is 1.0.66.0
Target Framework is 4.0
Local copy for System.Data.SQLite is ON.
In web.config I have 
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>


What my be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I noticed that I used two instances of `InMemoryDatabaseTest`. I deleted one instance from the test.